# Problems with data view and use in kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new in kibana and elasticsearch. I need to use and visualize the data that i have in my local elasticsearch db, in the management -> dev tools module i can see my data, but in the dashboard part i only see the timestamp.

i change a lot of times the mapping part and change the logic to have the timestamp at the beggining of the mapping part. What can i do to solve this and see my data in the discover part?.  Thanks in advance :)

Here are some screenshots of the discover and the mapping that i'm using:

[Discover visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7K45.png)
[mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93nOP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for nested fields in [Kibana got a first release in 7.6](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-7-6-0-released), but with the following features

1. Index Patterns will detect Nested Fields correctly
2. You will be able to watch Nested Fields in Discover (not the value but field name)
3. Filtering on Nested Fields via the filter bar works
4. KQL allows searching for nested fields (see the KQL documentation
   for an explanation of the syntax for querying nested fields)

**As a result, you can't see the data in the nested field type in Discover right now. (I test it with ESv8.8)**

You can follow this [GitHub task](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084) for future information.

Currently, the only way to create visualization with nested fields is Vega. Here is an [example](https://mafiaguy.medium.com/how-to-create-a-visualization-for-nested-objects-templates-ed2c42facb6d).

[image]